# Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Bom dia, estou tentado fazer o **deploy** da aplicação no emulador do **andoid**, mas está dando esse erro, já tentei *alterar a porta*, mas não deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar?

> Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>   Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)

Comment: Já conferiu se o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento está configurado corretamente, como explicado no link que retona do erro?

Comment: Está sim, todas as variáveis de ambiente está setadas corretamente, mas quando rodo o react-native run-android, esse erro aparece, já alterei a porta, mas nada